# OLAP for a large excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, olap

I´m having issues with a giant excel spreadsheet. It has like 300 thousand rows and need to make a pivot table with all that data (impossible to divide). As you could think, it take hours to process. I tried access with same results.

I need to make it faster, it's olap my best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [PowerPivot](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/bi/powerpivot.aspx). It is a free addon for Excel 2010 and ideal for handling large data in Excel.

Here is a decent [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0789743159) about Powerpivot.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a fan of MS Access, but this is actually one of those times where it might do the job nicely, provided you don't need multiple Values in your pivot table.

Just import the Spreadsheet as-is and run a cross-tab query.